# Catching if a text was selected

Tags: javascript, html

This code below from [select document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event)  adds '`You selected: ${selection}`' when you select text inside input box. Can I modify it to operate whenever I select any text, not just the one in certain id?

html

```
<input value="Try selecting some text in this element.">
<p id="log"></p>
```

javascript

```
function logSelection(event) {
const log = document.getElementById('log');
const selection = event.target.value.substring(event.target.selectionStart, event.target.selectionEnd);
log.textContent = `You selected: ${selection}`;
}

const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('select', logSelection);
```

I've tried using `querySelector` instead of `getElementById` after adding `<body>` part to html but it didn't work

```
function textSelection(event) {
  const selection = event.target.value.substring(event.target.selectionStart, event.target.selectionEnd);
  alert(selection)
}

const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.addEventListener('select', textSelection);
```

Comment: Do you want this for `input`/`textarea` elements, or all elements (including non-inputs like `div`s)?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

> The [select] event is not available for all elements in all languages. For example, in HTML, select events can be dispatched only on form  and  elements. ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event))

You could try to workaround it by, for example, detecting when a mouse down -> move -> up sequence is fired.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let state = {};
div.addEventListener('mousedown', () => state.down = true);
div.addEventListener('mousemove', () => state.movedWhileDown = state.down);
div.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (state.movedWhileDown)
    console.log('maybe you selected text?');
  state = {};
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```